# PHP search inside array

Tags: php, arrays, search

Array

```
( 
[1] => Array 
( 
[A] => Rina
[B] => Reding 
[C] => 9987536263 
[D] => 47 
[E] => NO 
) 

[2] => Array 
( 
[A] => Anna 
[B] => Jones 
[C] => 0243055454 
[D] => 90 
[E] => YES 
) 

[3] => Array 
( 
[A] => Mario 
[B] => Arinken 
[C] => 5654678679 
[D] => 80 
[E] => YES
) 

)
```

How can I search inside this Array output with the GET function when get is i.e. [C]? 
The result should look like this: Your result: [D] Exam passed: [E]
i.e.  GET is **5654678679** and the result 
is: ***Your result: 80 Exam passed: YES***
Example http://goo.gl/rkJwfU 
This array is generated with "Excel to PHP array"

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array=Array( 
1 => Array 
( 
'A' => 'Rina',
'B' => 'Reding',
'C' => 9987536263,
'D' => 47,
'E' => 'NO' 
),

2 => Array 
( 
'A' => 'Anna',
'B' => 'Jones',
'C' => '0243055454',
'D' => 90,
'E' => 'YES' 
),

3 => Array 
( 
'A' => 'Mario',
'B' => 'Arinken',
'C' => '5654678679',
'D' => 80,
'E' => 'YES'
) 

);

//$pc=$_GET["PERSONAL_CODE"];
$pc='5654678679';//Test Case
$C=array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
  $C[$v['C']]=$k;
}

echo "Your result: ".$array[$C[$pc]]['D']." Exam passed:".$array[$C[$pc]]['E'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you are looking for something like [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search) or [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array)

Comment: i'm newbie in php, so i need help to solve this